# Why can't I convert a Number into a Double?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

`weight` is a field (Number in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)), set as `100`.

```
int weight = json['weight'];
double weight = json['weight'];
```

`int weight` works fine, returns `100` as expected, but `double weight` crashes (`Object.noSuchMethod` exception) rather than returning `100.0`, which is what I expected.

However, the following works:

```
num weight = json['weight'];
num.toDouble();
```

Comment: `double weight = json['weight'].toDouble()`?

Comment: you can do like this: `double weight = json['weight'] + 0.0;`

Comment: it's Dart, not Flutter per se.  Dart is insanely strict with typing.  ultimately, it makes for cleaner code.  but it takes a bit to get used to it - Dart won't just magically convert variables for you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When parsing `100` from Firestore (which actually does not support a "number type", but [converts it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)), it will by standard be parsed to an **`int`**.
*Dart* does not automatically "smartly" cast those types. In fact, you cannot cast an `int` to a `double`, which is the problem you are facing. If it were possible, your code would just work fine.

#### Parsing

Instead, you can *parse* it yourself:

```
double weight = json['weight'].toDouble();
```

#### Casting

What also works, is parsing the JSON to a `num` and then assigning it to a `double`, which will cast `num` to `double`.

```
double weight = json['weight'] as num;
```

This seems a bit odd at first and in fact the [Dart Analysis tool](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) (which is e.g. built in into the Dart plugin for VS Code and IntelliJ) will mark it as an **"unnecessary cast"**, which it is not.

```
double a = 100; // this will not compile

double b = 100 as num; // this will compile, but is still marked as an "unnecessary cast"
```

`double b = 100 as num` compiles because [`num` is the super class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/num-class.html) of [`double`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/double-class.html) and Dart casts super to sub types even without explicit casts.
An **explicit cast** would be the follwing:

```
double a = 100 as double; // does not compile because int is not the super class of double

double b = (100 as num) as double; // compiles, you can also omit the double cast
```

[Here is a nice read](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/05/types-and-casting-in-dart.html) about *"Types and casting in Dart"*.

#### Explanation

What happened to you is the following:

```
double weight;

weight = 100; // cannot compile because 100 is considered an int
// is the same as
weight = 100 as double; // which cannot work as I explained above
// Dart adds those casts automatically
```

Comment: This is mostly wrong. Dart never converts an integer value to a double for you, you have to call `.toDouble()`. Doing an `as` cast on a number does not change its type. If you run `double x = 42 as num;` on the VM, you will get a run-time error because the integer is not a double. It works when compiled to JavaScript, but only because all number instances in JavaScript are doubles, even the ones that are also `int`.

Comment: @lrn It works fine. I tested it before posting.. You could have also checked out what I linked.

Comment: I'm probably misreading what you are writing, and if so, I apologize. I'm very confused about what it is that you say is working (the `.toDouble()` works, everything else does not when run on the VM, but it's not clear from the text that it's examples that are not supposed to work). The "Parsing" part is actually casting from int to double, the "Casting" part is doing things that all fails at run-time. So, maybe I'm just saying that the message isn't clear.

Comment: Not sure which link you are referring to, but I'm quite familiar with the Dart type system and run-time behavior. I'm speaking from the perspective of the Dart 2 static and run-time type system, but what I say here also goes for Dart 1 in `--checked` more (which checks types instead of ignoring them and allowing anything).

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in one line:

```
 double weight = (json['weight'] as num).toDouble();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can Parse the data Like given below:

Here document is a `Map<String,dynamic>`

```
double opening = double.tryParse(document['opening'].toString());
```

Comment: this can safely go as a comment

Answer (score 1):

In Dart, `int` and `double` are separate types, both subtypes of `num`.

There is no automatic conversion between number types. If you write:

```
num n = 100;
double d = n;
```

you will get a run-time error. Dart's static type system allows unsafe down-casts, so the unsafe assignment of `n` to `d` (unsafe because not all `num` values are `double` values) is treated implicitly as:

```
num n = 100;
double d = n as double;
```

The `as double` *checks* that the value is actually a `double` (or `null`), and throws if it isn't. If that check succeeds, then it can safely assign the value to `d` since it is known to match the variable's type.

That's what's happening here. The actual value of `json['weight']` (likely with static type `Object` or `dynamic`) is the `int` object with value 100. Assigning that to `int` works. Assigning it to `num` works. Assigning it to `double` throws.

The Dart JSON parser parses numbers as integers if they have no decimal or exponent parts (`0.0` is a double, `0e0` is a double, `0` is an integer). That's very convenient in most cases, but occasionally annoying in cases like yours where you want a `double`, but the code creating the JSON didn't write it as a double.

In cases like that, you just have to write `.toDouble()` on the values when you extract them. That's a no-op on actual doubles.

As a side note, Dart compiled to JavaScript represents all numbers as the JavaScript Number type, which means that all numbers are doubles. In JS compiled code, all integers can be assigned to double without conversion. That will *not* work when the code is run on a non-JS implementation, like Flutter, Dart VM/server or ahead-of-time compilation for iOS, so don't depend on it, or your code will not be portable.

Comment: You do not get a run time error. I do not see where you got that from. Maybe that was once the case, but you can try it on the VM. There is neither a compile nor run time error.

Comment: Just tried: `main() { num n = 100; double d = n; }` run on the Dart 2 VM gives `Unhandled exception:                                                                
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'`. Adding the `as double` makes no difference. The assignment used to work in *unchecked* Dart 1 code, but if you use `--checked` when running Dart 1, it would fail in exactly the same way. An `int` is not a `double`. (Again, when compiling to JavaScript, integers actually are doubles too, because JavaScript only has one numeric type).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

double weight = json['weight'] == null ? 0.00 : (json['weight'] as num).toDouble();