# Flutter/Dart: Cast int to double in Widget Param not working

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, int, double

I'm trying casting a int to double in flutter/dart at param fontSize from Text  Widget but I have this exception:

"Another exception was thrown: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast"

I have been follow the instructions here: [Why can't I convert a Number into a Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345345/why-cant-i-convert-a-number-into-a-double)  but that's not working yet.

here is Text inside my component widget:

```
class ButtonLogin extends MaterialButton {
  ButtonLogin({this.fontSize, ...});

final fontSize;
...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
double fontSizeDouble = (fontSize as num) as double; 
...
Text(
 label,
 style: TextStyle(
   fontSize: fontSizeDouble,
   color: labelColor,
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
 ),
),
...
}
```

Out from component I'm passing at param fontSize a Int value like this:

```
...
 ButtonLogin(
      backgroundColor: ColorsCustom.loginScreenUp,
      labelColor: Colors.white,
      label: 'Back to other session?',
      fontSize: 16,
      mOnPressed: () => _login(),
 );
...
```

the ellipsis is just to indicate there is more of code, its not part of code.

Comment: Hello, I am not getting any error. An advice I can give you to avoid errors is to use data types in your code when you define variables.

Comment: tried to use `.toDouble()` before using the number?

Comment: Thanks @camillo777 , I just added type double after final , like this: 
" final double fontSize" , 
 and that's works.

Comment: @JuniorMachado I am glad it worked, if it helped you can you press on the up arrow to say it was useful? Thank you!

Comment: @camillo777  I tried , but I have a return: "You can't vote for your own post"  ,  I'm did something wrong? :(

Comment: Hello @Junior Machado, I have written my comment as an answer so you can accept it if you want. Thank you

Comment: @camillo777  Course, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting any error. An advice I can give you to avoid errors is to use data types in your code when you define variables.